# magnificPopup used in legend of fieldset doesn't open popup but instead opens in same window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, magnific-popup

I am trying to use a popup to open an image which is linked behind the legend of a fieldset.
However, the image opens in the same tab, leaving the original page.

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>
      <a id="popup" class="popup" href="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTGbPN1_Hbi1_rjpOJ3jKoIE_tWIfDn_ZtW4npAGr30VsNWD3CIvg&s">TEST:</a>
    </legend>
    <p>
      TESTTEST
    </p>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

.

```
$("#popup").on('click', function() {
  $('a[class=popup]').attr('href').magnificPopup({
    type: 'image'
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Colar/na6mqdLv/9/

Comment: It's working [just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/5Lmchk10/) - You just need to read the documentation

Comment: Yes I tried that approach, but when introducing it to the whole program it still doesnt work: https://jsfiddle.net/Colar/na6mqdLv/18/ 
I'm sorry about the confusion, I thought the simplified code would suffice, but that is clearly not the case.

Comment: No, it's still working [just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/csyeL8wq/) - You just didn't include the `magnificPopup` sources (JS+CSS) to the fiddle :)

Comment: Well, that's 3 hours of my life I'll never get back :D